# Spyne add method dynamically

Tags: python, soap, spyne

I am using Spyne to implement a SOAP server to allow client conduct 'RPC'.

I want know if I have already started the server and I want to add some methods, in what way can I achieve this without stopping the server?

I always did this by stopping and restarting it again. But if I want to make this server public, it's not a good way to do that.

Can someone give me a solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to restart your service anyway.

But for production purpose you can provide interface to your service through nginx or apache2 web server(mod_proxy can pass all post data to your service). In this way Nginx/apache called [reverse-proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), clients send data to this server and get response, but real work is done behind the scene.

In this configuration you can switch between two sevices(old and new one) faster